# Why is my JavaScript code not accepted as the right answer?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this Javascript exercise: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards

I am wondering why the solution below is not an accepted answer:

```
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const low = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  const high = [10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'];

  if (low.includes(card)) {
    count += 1;
  }

  else if (high.includes(card)) {
    count -= 1;
  }

  let decision;

  if (count > 0) {decision = "Bet"}
  else {decision = "Hold"}

  return count + decision;
  // Only change code above this line
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

When I am comparing it to accepted answers I don't see what they are doing differently. One thing that is not clear to me in the assignment is that should `return` be called every time or only after the last function call (`cc('A');`).

Comment: I guess the only thing you are missing is a space between count and decision

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao is correct. The expected output of your function is "5 Bet" but your function outputs "5Bet". Fixing that makes this code pass the challenge.

Comment: This was embarasing. I had `console.log` statement before return statent to see what was going on and it had the correct output, but I did not notice that return statement was missing the space. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to comment why you didn't `console.log()` your output. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space between count and decision

```
  return count + " " + decision;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving an answer in the wrong format. Just missing the space between count and decision.

Incorrect:`return count + decision;`

Correct:`return count +" "+ decision;`